# Loading xml, linq with namespace using c#

Tags: c#, xml

I am following a tutorial and it works fine when i load a basic xml file.

### xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Students>
  <Student ID="1">
    <Name>Test1</Name>
  </Student>
  <Student ID="2">
    <Name>Test2</Name>
  </Student>
  <Student ID="3">
    <Name>Test3 </Name>
  </Student>
</Students>
```

---

### C#

```
XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\b\Desktop\SITE\xml.xml");
var students = from student in testXML.Descendants("Student")
               select new
               {
                   ID = student.Attribute("ID").Value
               };

foreach (var student in students)
{
    xmlTitle.Text += "</br>" + student.ID + " </br>";

}
```

### output:

[image]

Now, I want to add this tag before the

```
<Students>
```

---

```
<outputTree xmlns="http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms/spss-output-1.8.xsd">
```

I tried for ages but i cant get it working. when i add

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/xml/oms";
```

Comment: What error do you get or unexpected output?

Comment: *"Before the"* Before what?

Comment: Tried for ages what?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You cannot add any tags before "Students" node, because "Students" is the root.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
XDocument testXML = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\b\Desktop\SITE\xml.xml");
var students = from student in testXML.Descendants()
               where student.Name.LocalName == "Student"
               select student;    

foreach (var student in students)
{
    xmlTitle.Text += "</br>" + student.Attribute("ID").Value + " </br>";

}
```